# Can we use browser sync on external url

Tags: browser-sync

I am pretty new on browser-sync

Lets say I have a URL (www.dominos.com) that I need to perform testing. Can I pass this URL and do the browser compatibility testing on different browsers  Or this is a tool only for developers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsersync is not a browser compatibility tester, it's a development tool that among other things (this is where the name comes from) synchronizes the across multiple screens.

I suspect you got it mixed up with [BrowserStack](https://www.browserstack.com/start), which *is* a (paid) browser tester and which you'll find pretty straight forward - you just paste in the URL.